# Contact Activity Report (or Contact report with Activity Cross-Filter)

Tags: reporting, cross-filter, activities, tasks

Does anyone know of a way to gather Contacts **without** activities within a certain time frame (ie: 30 days) and **not** assigned to a specific user?

I've tried a Contact report with the cross filter of "AND Contacts *without* Activities, Date *not equal to* LAST 30 DAYS, Assigned To *not equal to* (user)".

The above doesn't seem to filter correctly. I tried to reverse the Activities Filters but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Which part isn't filtering correctly?  Have you tried each individual filter separately to make sure it is correct?

Comment: Which Date field are you using on Activities?

Comment: Mike: Good idea. I'll try each individually to check and post an update.

Benj: I'm using "Due Date" on Activities.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a solution for you:

1. Created a report based on Accounts and Contacts
2. Added a regular filter on Contact Owner (e.g. Contact Owner not equal [user name])
3. Added a cross-filter for Contacts with Activities
4. Sub cross-filter for Activity Created Date equals "Last 30 days"

[image]

If you want to also pull in Activity data, you should consider a Custom Report Type (CRT), as well.

1. Click My Name -> Setup -> App Setup -> Create -> Report Types
2. Choose Contacts as your base object
3. Fill in the required fields and then choose Activities for your relationship
4. Build a report using your new CRT

[image]

Comment: I think I just resolved the issue this morning (before reading your answer). I'll post a more detailed update, but I did go the direction of a CRT (realized yesterday) and created an initial filter like the one above, but related to an Activity field instead.

Comment: Excellent - I look forward to seeing what the solution was.